# C# DrawNode actualize

Tags: c#, drawing, nodes, treenode

I have a problem with Treeview. I just put only color square into node text, so I overwrite function "treeView1_DrawNode".
I have a lot of nodes, about 100 and I actualize text of them every 5 seconds.
Problem is with actualization. When I actualize one node function "DrawNode" is working for entire nodes. It take a lot of time and it make artefacts on the screen.

Function is really simple.

```
private void treeView1_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
            Rectangle tempRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + 1, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height);
            if (e.Node.IsSelected)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, tempRect);
            }

            SolidBrush redBrush = new SolidBrush(e.Node.BackColor);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(redBrush, e.Bounds.X + 2, e.Bounds.Y + 2, 12, 12);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Aqua, e.Bounds.X + 2, e.Bounds.Y + 2, 12, 12);

            tempRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + 12, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics,
                                   e.Node.Text,
                                   e.Node.TreeView.Font,
                                   tempRect,
                                   e.Node.ForeColor);
    }
```

Comment: There are no magic solutions to this.  Consider updating the treeview in bulk, not just one node at a time, using BeginUpdate() before you start and EndUpdate() after you're done.

Comment: @HansPassant - it working as I want. That's the point. I just want to update all text in nodes and on the end repaint once. Thank you very much. :D